# Can't delete partition on USB Stick after using Startup Disk Creator

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb, format

I created an Ubuntu install usb stick using the tool Startup Disk Creator. However I want to re-use this usb stick but I can't delete big partition this tool made, neither on ubuntu (using GParted) nor Windows 10 Disk Manager.

Help?

Comment: Why can't you delete the partition using gparted? Can you create a new patition table?

Comment: Are you trying to do this while the usb stick is (auto) mounted? You must `umount` it first. While it's mounted, partition info is stored in two places - on the "disk" drive and in kernel memory. To avoid the confusion (which one is right?) of having to update the info in two places, it's simply locked.

Comment: @Pilot6 It worked. Thanks. What is the default partition table for usb sticks msdos?

Comment: msdos is the most compatible one

Answer (score 1):

Use `gparted` and create a new partition table.

Then you can create one or more partitions.

Comment: Weird solution, but it worked!